# How do I install Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects (SMO) for SQL 2017 without Visual Studio?

Tags: smo

Here's the scenario, we're installing Microsoft Dynamics 365 (Formerly CRM) v9 On Prem on SQL 2017.  RTM is only compatible with SQL 2016, but as of update 0.03 it does support SQL 2017.  Using a Setup script I can install the latest update (0.22) during installation, but the installer only installs the SQL components for SQL 2016 and not 2017.  So when using it I get errors about missing CLR Type and SMO for Sql 2017.  I was able to get CLR Type installed using SQL 2017 Feature Pack, but they have removed SMO from this, it's only installable through a Nuget package in Visual Studio from what I'm seeing.

I would rather not install Visual Studio on our Dynamics 365 web servers just to get this package.  One work around I found was I installed SSMS 18 which added it, but again I'd rather not install any dev tools on the web servers just to get SMO.  Does anyone have other options on how to satisfy this requirement?  I tried some PowerShell scripts that supposedly would install it, but nothing worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both admin and web access on the target host you can simply install SMO via PowerShell package manager:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects -Version 161.44091.28
```

Alternatively you can download the NuGet package manually from:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/161.44091.28

move it to `"-o$env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies"` and register by:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name "SMO" -SourceLocation "location" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module SMO
```